# How to remove python 2.7.15rc1 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python-2.7, software-uninstall

When I checked Python version as normal user, it is showing Python 2:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

And when try to run as root :

```
# python --version
Python 3.6.7
```

Any suggestion how to remove this Python 2.7

Comment: If your main goal is to call python3 when you run `python`, you must define aliases in .bashrc instead of removing python. Messing up python may cause your system to break.

Answer (score 18):

You need to define the two different python versions

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.NN 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.NN 2
```

Then you need to choose which version should be defined as default

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.NN
```

Note! You need to check what version you have of python and replace NN with your version.

```
python2 --version
python3 --version
```

Comment: Nice to hear, can you mark it as an answer then?

Comment: Worked like a charm , thank you very much.

Comment: but when I `sudo apt install python-pip`, it still installs with python2.7, not 3.

Comment: ok, got the point, I have to use the package name for python 3 as well:  `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: I get an error 'no alternatives for python' when I try this.

Comment: @BretHess Perhaps you could be a bit more informative